# writing the output of print function to a textfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, save, file-handling

I want to save ''contents'' to a new text file in python. I need to have all the words in lowercase to be able to find the word frequency. '''text.lower()''' didn't work. Here is the code;

```
text=open('page.txt', encoding='utf8')
for x in text:
print(x.lower())
```

I want to save the results of print to a new text file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `file` parameter in `print` to directly print the output of `print(...)` to your desired file.

```
text=open('page.txt', encoding='utf8')
text1=open('page1.txt', mode='x',encoding='utf8') #New text file name it according to you
for x in text:
    print(x.lower(),file=text1)
text.close()
text1.close()
```

Note: Use `with` while operating on files. As you don't have to explicitly use `.close` it takes care of that.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening the file `page.txt` for reading, but it's not open to write. Since you want to save to a new text file, you might also open `new_page.txt` where you write all of the lines in `page.txt` lowercased:

```py
# the with statement is the more pythonic way to open a file
with open('page.txt') as fh:

    # open the new file handle in write mode ('w' is for write, 
    # it defaults to 'r' for read
    with open('new_page.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in fh:
            # write the lowercased version of each line to the new file
            outfile.write(line.lower())
```

The important thing to note is that the `with` statement negates the need for you to close the file, even in the case of an error

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys 
stdoutOrigin=sys.stdout 
sys.stdout = open("yourfilename.txt", "w")
#Do whatever you need to write on the file here.
sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout=stdoutOrigin
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: While this post may answer the question, code-only answers are often considered low-quality. Please provide some rationale / text explanation as to why this is the correct answer, even if short.